# Font-face not working in ubuntu for a site done with wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, ubuntu, fonts

Here is the thing I just uploaded to a remote server a site developed in wordpress with a custom web font using Font-face and it works fine in OS Windows and Mac the issue is when viewing the site in an Ubuntu, and I assume, others Linux enviroments.

This is the font-face chunk of code I use in the style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'vijayaregular';
    src: url('./estilos/vijaya-webfont.eot');
    src: url('./estilos/vijaya-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('./estilos/vijaya-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./estilos/vijaya-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./estilos/vijaya-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('./estilos/vijaya-webfont.svg#vijayaregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And this is how I call the font type:

```
body{
    background:#ffedbc;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family: "vijaya", "open sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#970d34;
}
```

This issue only happens in Ubuntu, as I said before, the code doesn't seems to be loading any of the fonts but Sans-serif.

I leave the site so you can have a look, please nevermind the two stylesheets and two jQuery links that was just me trying crazy stuff.
here it is: www.baccotrattoria.com.co

Any responses will be welcome!

Thanks before hand!

Comment: You have given the wrong font name in your body. It should be  `font-family: "vijayaregular", "open sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`

Comment: Thanks I think it does the trick, I'm doing it int the browser's console now and it seems to work even thought it shows some errors with the spacing at the footer, I'll have a look later if the same happens on windows... Thanks a lot!